# Entity Framework 6 doing relationships wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So, I have three classes

```
public class ParameterType
{
public ParameterType(){}

public int ParameterTypeId;
public string Type;

}

public class Parameter
{
public int ParameterId;
public string Description;
public int ParameterTypeId;
public virtual ParameterType ParameterType;
}

public class Analysis
{
public Analysis()
{
   ParameterList = new List<Parameter>();
}

public int Id;
public int Number;
public string Description;
public virtual List<Parameter> ParameterList;


}
```

It properly maps relationship between `Parameter` and `ParameterType` (FK in `Parameter`, if i try to insert id which doesnt exist I get an error - correct)
Now, `Analysis` has set of parameters, for example if it `analysis` has 5 parameters I should insert 5 records with same `Number` and different `parameterId`. How do I achieve that?

Also, how do I insert it with code? I've tried this:

```
List<Parameter> paramList = new ParamList<Parameter>
paramList.Add(new Parameter(){ParameterId = 2});
paramList.Add(new Parameter(){ParameterId = 3});
Analysis analysis = new Analysis()
analysis.ParameterList = paramList;
ctx.Add(analysis);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

But all I got was 2 new records in `Parameter` table and one in `Analysis` WITHOUT link do `Parameters`.
Should I iterate through collection and add new `Analysis` record for each `Parameter` with corresponding `ParameterId`? (so I should add `public int ParameterId` in Analysis class?)
Tried to follow http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx but it gave me `AnalysisId` in `Parameters` table (I did exactly way presented on the page, checked few times)

Comment: I don't see any code that actually *Configures One-to-Many relationship using Fluent API:* as suggested by your link.  Did you configure the relationships?

Comment: Little confused by the question though the first thing I see is that you're using 2 slightly different conventions for your primary keys. In your parameter and parameter type you're using `[className]Id` and in analysis you're using just `ID` - both are acceptable for EF, though not sure if mixing them is causing the issues you're having. Try to stick to a single convention.

Comment: How can you do `ctx.Add(analysis)`? Which `Add` method is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I see the problem; however, the question is a little difficult to understand, so I apologize if I posted this as an answer when I really should have used a comment to get clarification.

Since you are wanting Analysis to have a collection of Parameters, you need to either describe that relationship using fluent as indicated by Erik Philips or add a foreign key and a navigation property to your Parameter class so that EF understands the relationship.

Your code would look something like this...notice that I have changed the name of your ID property on the Analysis class, as also suggested by Darren.

```
public class Parameter
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    ...
    [ForeignKey("AnalysisId")]
    public Analysis Analysis { get; set; }
    public int AnalysisId { get; set; }
}

public class Analysis
{
    ...
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AnalysisId { get; set; }

    virtual public ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

On the other hand, if you would like to assign Parameters to more than one Analysis, then you'll need to change this method slightly and use an intermediate table because that implies a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class Parameter
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    ...
    virtual public ICollection<Analysis> Analyses { get; set; }
}

public class Analysis
{
    ...
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AnalysisId { get; set; }

    virtual public ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

EF will map this for you; however, it will require a specifically named table with specifically named columns. I prefer to map this using fluent, which you accomplish by modifying your DbContext object.  DbContext has a virtual method called OnModelCreating that gets a DbModelBuilder. You can express relationships using the fluent syntax like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParameterConfiguration());
}
```

That goes in the class that extends DbContext. ParameterConfiguration is a class that you create that derives from EntityTypeConfiguration, like this:

```
public class ParameterConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parameter>
{
    public ParameterConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(t => t.Analyses)
            .WithMany(t => t.Parameters)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ParamsForAnalyses")
                .MapLeftKey("ParameterId")
                .MapRightKey("AnalysisId"));
    }
}
```

Now, create a table called "ParamsForAnalyses" and give it two columns, ParameterId and AnalysisId. EF will use that table to manage many-to-many relationships between Parameter and Analysis. Create the relationships is simple...just add a Parameter to the Parameters collection in an Analysis proxy that you've gotten from EF, or add an Analysis to a Parameter proxy, and then call SaveChanges.

(EF creates proxies based on your classes.) I'm pretty sure you can get away with just adding one side of the relationship and EF creates the other...no need to add a Parameter to an Analysis and an Analysis to a Parameter to express the relationship...just one or the other.

Comment: Notice also that I'm using some data annotations that weren't included in your example.

Comment: good catch, I didnt use annotations or fluent api, on this website I've posted this guy didnt use any of those in the first example. Will try it

Anyway, your example confuses me a bit. We got AnalysisId - which is primary key. One Analysis can have few parameters (so there would be few rows with same AnalysisId and different parameters). If AnalysisId is primary key then I guess it's impossible to do?

Or EF will handle that and create additional table linking those two, with two columns: AnalysisId and ParameterId?

Comment: AnalysisId in the class Parameter is a foreign key, even though it's a primary key in the Analysis class. In this case, I don't believe EF will require the intermediate table...unless you wanted a many-to-many relationship between Parameter and Analysis.

I read into your initial question that you want Analysis records with zero or many Parameter records. And, further that you wanted, Parameter records with one ParameterType record each.

Comment: If I was correct in my assumption that you want an optional one to many relationship between Analysis and Parameter, then EF should handle the mapping for you with just the analysis foreign key on parameter, the backward navigation property, and the forward navigation property implied by the virtual collection of Parameters in the Analysis class.  (I think)

Comment: Why would you put foreign key in the Parameter?
Maybe I understand it wrong, but let's assume:
Analysis 1 Param 1,2,3
Analysis 2 Param 2,3,5
Analysis 3 Param 1,2,4
If you put a key in Param table, then you can't use same parameter in different Analysis?

Comment: That is correct. My suggestion assumes that you would only assign one Analysis record to each Parameter. I'll amend my answer to support a suggestion for assigning the same Parameter to multiple Analysis records.

Comment: @Raston, I have modified my answer to show an example of the expression of a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for. My initial post was "a bit" unclear :) Thanks, marked as answer